# SharePoint Chatbot - Add to every page on SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, chatbot

I am new to Microsoft Cognitive Services. I want to develop a simple FAQ chatbot. Which consumes Q & A from a SharePoint online list and displays answers in Chatbot. 
Is it possible to have this bot added on each and every page on SharePoint? Can we add it as iframe to MasterPage which will result it to be embedded on every page?

[Reference here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-webchat?view=azure-bot-service-4.0).

*Any inputs on this would be super helpful. 
Thanks!*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options for doing the same:

1) Publish the Web Chat channel and add using Iframe (not recommended)

2) [Publish Direct Line Channel and add using jQuery](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat)

We added using second approach. Add the div and jQuery to masterpage and it would appear on each page(Classic site, Classic pages)

Answer (score 0):

I would add it as an site extension on every site collection. See following documentation from Microsoft regarding Site extensions and SharePoint framework [Overview of SharePoint Framework Extensions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/overview-extensions)